# Sitecore Horizon missing sc_horizon=api in the request

Tags: horizon

I have installed Sitecore Horizon in production. I cannot select the **Main Site** using the dropdown and getting the following error in console.

[image: dropdown]

```
Uncaught (in promise): Require API Horizon mode. Current mode: Disabled. Ensure that the request URL contains 'sc_horizon=api' in the query string.
```

[image: error]

When I select any other site using the dropdown then it loads fine without any errors.

This is the request in the horizon log

```
Sending HTTP request "GET" https://prd-sc10.mirvac.com/sitecore/api/ssc/horizon/languages/?sc_horizon=api&sc_site=Main Site
```

I have reinstalled horizon a few times and checked all the configs but could not figure out any issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page application (**Horizon**) requires a site that handles all requests.

We have got the same error in the Sitecore Pages application after we marked the website as internal (`isInternal="true"`). All other custom sites, we had in our solution, were configured to handle requests from specific hosts only.

To fix the issue we had to either ensure one of our sites could handle all requests or introduce one more non-internal site (registered before the website) that handles all requests and pointed to not existing content item (to hide it from the site selection list in pages).

Hope this helps.